# Line height of wrapping text in list items

Tags: css

On the http://steve.brettatkin.com/projects.php when you hover over "Work", a sub-menu appears. The 4th and 5th links have text that wraps.  How do I decrease the line-height so that the second line of the link doesn't look like a new link?

I've tried a combination of margin/padding/line-height on the `<li>` but it isn't working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `line-height` from the `<a>` inside your `<li>`s and put it on the `<li>`s instead, then use `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` for the margin between the `<li>`s and use the `line-height` for the `line-height` of single `<li>`s

(making the hover state of the `<a>`s there bold also makes the menu jump when hovering cause it no longer always fits on 1 line)

Comment: I tried this and it fixed it, thanks. I had the correct declarations, just the wrong selectors...tired and slow at 4am...

Comment: Love a concise and useful answer - thanks for not lecturing on how this has all been documented in some obscure blog!

Answer (score 5):

I usually solve that by using `x` padding-left and `-x` text-indent. This way the text that wraps will be indented, but not the first line.

```
#navigation li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-indent: -10px;
}
```

If you want to change the line-height, however, take notice that you will need some sort of margin from the previous items - otherwise they'll just compress together as well. Maybe:

```
#navigation li a {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
/* a in (li next to li) = only second item and forward */
#navigation li+li a {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line-height current set for the drop down lists on your menu is 25px. Try lowering this to half that:

```
line-height: 14px;
```

You may need to up the margin-bottom of the parent LI element then from 3px to counter the reduced line-height of the link elements.

Adding this to the sub  tags should sort it:

```
line-height: 14px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
```

You might want to add the latter to the LI rather than the A.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the other solution first and it worked.  It appears you're suggesting the same thing, so I'm sure it would have fixed it as well.